# onclick not working with the pagination on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

We have the table with pagination when we click on the elements first elements have the adding listeners and next pages not adding listeners.Click is not working on tables. 
Here is my code please Help me.
And this my table

```
<table id="data_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 1 Label</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 1 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 2 Label</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 2 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 3 Label</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 3 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 4 Label</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 4 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 5 Label</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 5 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 6 Label</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 6 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 7 Label</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 7 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 8 Data 1</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 8 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hello">
            <td>Row 9 Data 1</td>
            <td>
                <select class="user-selection">
                    <option>Row 9 Data</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my jquery

```
$(function () {
    var dataTable = $('#data_table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 6
    });

    var allDropDowns = dataTable.$('select');
    $.each(allDropDowns, function (index, dropdown) {
        console.log(dropdown.value);
    })


});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr#hello").click(function() {
        alert("hello");
    });  
});
```

Click is working fine with the 1st pagination and not working on other pagenations.

Comment: @vikrantsingh can you please provide the jsfiddle example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wtx0g8rf/ fiddle

Comment: The `id` should be unique. All your rows have `id="hello"`. Please change it before anything else.

Comment: @vikrantsingh  i am getting this error Please help me.TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

$('#example').on("click","tr#dialog-confirm",function() {

Comment: add a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or update your code .where are you getting  `$(...).on is not a function` error

Comment: @vikrantsingh Here is the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/kva6w98g/ using jquery jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Comment: Your [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kva6w98g/4/) working fine ,there is no any error , Have you added `jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js` for `column-filter` addon??

Comment: @vikrantsingh Thank you and how can i download the code please help me.

Comment: @vikrantsingh Can you please provide the checkbox selection based on coloumn showing in this example

Comment: @vikrantsingh How can we Dynamically update the tables.

Comment: Example with checkboxes http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/kva6w98g/10/,Dyanmically update what??(a column ,a row or whole data ??) Look at the `api` (https://datatables.net/api) methods `fnUpdate()`,`fnAddData` etc. :)

Comment: @vikrantsingh For updates records once check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eLsknm0f/1/

Comment: Please add a new question with description for what you want ,dont ask whole new question in the comments ,Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery On Method.

Change the code like this:

```
  $(document).on('click','tr#hello', function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: can you please provide the alter native of this